# How to use InsertOrReplace in sqlite.net PCL?

Tags: xamarin, sqlite.net

I am using the PCL version of sqlite.net from here (https://github.com/oysteinkrog/SQLite.Net-PCL).

Here is my simple class.

```
    public class LogEntry
    {
      [PrimaryKey, AutoIncrement]
      public int Key { get; set;}
      public DateTime Date { get; set; }
    }
```

When a new instance of LogEntry is created, the Key is automatically set to 0.  I set the Date to something and then call InsertOrReplace.  The record does get saved in my database.  The Key field gets the autoincrement value which happens to be 0 since it is the first record.

I then create a new instance of LogEntry (Key is automatically initialized to 0) and set the date to something else.  I then call InsertOrReplace.  Since there is an existing record with a Key of 0 that record gets updated.

What is the proper way to deal with this?  I considered initializing the Key to -1, but that didn't seem to work either.

Does anyone have an example of this working?

Comment: Is there a reason why you call InsertOrReplace instead of Insert?

Comment: You shouldn't use `InsertOrReplace` with an `AutoIncrement` primary key. It will always replace the register with Key `0`.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I experienced the same issue as you are describing. Try

```cs
var rowsAffected = Connection.Update(object);

if(rowsAffected == 0) {
    // The item does not exists in the database so lets insert it
    rowsAffected = Connection.Insert(object);
}

var success = rowsAffected > 0;

return success;
```

I just tried above and it works as expected

Comment: When you call update in the first line if the Id exists in the table the value gets updated. I mean how can it understand the object isn't already in db?

Comment: By checking if the primary key exists or not. In case of using AutoIncrement attribute with int/long the defaulted value is zero and not valid. (This is a guess but I assume it starts with the identity counting from one). So if the 'object' has Id = 0 then it knows it hasn't been inserted and hence Update returns zero.

Comment: But if you look at the original question that logic completely defiles your explanation.

Comment: Just re-read the question and now I'm slightly confused. Might be that I initially misread the question and in the example i wrote up didn't took into account the AutoIncrement key. Was some time now I worked with SQLite so cannot recall if I set any option to start seed at one. Need to try this out

Comment: The funny thing is your reply has been marked as answer! I used this one [link](http://stackoverflow.com/a/28704676/1729973) and it's working just fine.

Answer (score 30):

If you change the Key to a nullable type (int?) it should work. then SQLite sees null coming in and generates new id when needed.

```
public class LogEntry
    {
      [PrimaryKey, AutoIncrement]
      public int? Key { get; set;}
      public DateTime Date { get; set; }
    }
```

Comment: A better answer can be this one.

Answer (score 5):

The way this works is the source of much confusion but whereas `Insert` treats zeroed primary keys as a special case when `AutoIncrement` is set, `InsertOrReplace` does not.

So with:

```
[PrimaryKey, AutoIncrement]
public int id { get; set; }
```

if you `InsertOrReplace` a series of zero id records into a new table, the first will be stored at `id: 0` and each subsequent one will save over it. Whereas if you just `Insert` each one then because of the `AutoIncrement` the first will save at `id: 1` and the next at `id: 2` etc. as you might expect.

If you change the key type to a nullable int, then records with null ids will be treated as inserts by `InsertOrReplace`, and you don't actually need the `AutoIncrement` attribute at all in this case, they will still save in sequence starting at 1.

```
[PrimaryKey]
public int? id { get; set; }
```

If you can't use that for some reason you can do your own check for zero ids and for those call `Insert` instead, e.g.

```
Func<Foo, int> myInsertOrReplace = x => 
{ 
   return x.id == 0 ? _db.Insert(x) : _db.InsertOrReplace(x); 
};
```

but in this case you must use the `AutoIncrement` attribute, otherwise first zero insert will be saved at 0 and the second will throw a constraint exception when it attempts insert another such.

Answer (score 2):

To get the result you want, you need to make the id property of your class nullable. see here
[link](https://github.com/praeclarum/sqlite-net/issues/327)

Answer (score 0):

My solution for this is kind of similar to Joacar's, but instead of doing an update, I select the item, if it's null, I create a new item, otherwise update that items values, and then call InserOrReplace.

```
var existingKey = await this.GetItem(key);
Item item;

if (existingKey.Value != null)
{
    profile = new Item
    { 
        Id = existingKey.Id,
        Key = existingKey.Key,
        Value = newValue,
    };

    this.InsertOrReplaceAsync(item);
}
else
{
    item = new Item
    {
        Key = key,
        Value = value, 
    };

    this.InsertAsync(item);
}
```

It might not be optimal, but it worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

No need for InsertOrReplace.

Just await InsertAsync.

Guaranteed to work...

```
    if (object.ID != 0)
    {
      // Update an existing object.
      var T = DatabaseAsyncConnection.UpdateAsync(object);
      T.Wait();
      return T;
    }
    else
    {
      // Save a new object.
      var T = DatabaseAsyncConnection.InsertAsync(object);
      T.Wait();
      return T;
    }
```